# Error : Program type already present: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout$Behavior in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat, android-coordinatorlayout

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I have an error in the 2nd implementation with appcompat. I haven't succeded in solving it.

Answer (score 0):

your current support.design is :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

replace it with :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```